# VBA .font.bold optimization

Tags: vba, excel

I am formatting two different reports using the same macro.  The performance between the two spreadsheets is dramatically different.  The macro functions instantaneously on the first report and takes about 10 seconds on the other.  I have narrowed it down to the statement which makes cell A1 bold.  When the bolding statement is omitted, both spreadsheets execute the macro instantaneously.  I have tried the following methods of formatting cell A1.

1. ```
   Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
   ```
2. ```
   Range("A1:A1").Font.Bold = True
   ```
3. ```
   With Range("A1")
       .Font.Bold = True
   End With
   ```
4. ```
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
   ```

As far as I know, `.Font.Bold = True` is the only way to make a cell bold, so the problem cannot be circumvented by using another command.  The above are all the ways Google has suggested calling such action.  Both spreadsheets are .xls extensions.  Why might one spreadsheet's performance be dramatically different when executing the same statement?

Comment: Is it the only action you are performing on the spreadsheet? One thing I can think of is if you have an WorksheetChange event. It could also be a loop that goes too far. Could you post more of the code / explain what this is part of?

Comment: How are the two files different from each other? One much bigger? Other macros running in the background in one of them?

Comment: Save your workbook in `.xslb` format and it will start working quicker. Also turn of `Application.ScreenUpdating` when manipulating with the Worksheet formatting. Aside from that long story short - larger workbooks use more memory hence larger files will be noticeably slower than smaller ones.

Comment: WorksheetChange event doesn't fire when the font.bold is changed :) @DavidGM

Comment: is it possible to see the file(s)?

Comment: @ David GM: It is certainly not the only action I am performing.  However, I hesitate to post the entire code because when the bolding statement is removed, performance is identical between the spreadsheets.  It is not a matter of a loop going too far.  The bolding statement occurs after the loop has executed.

Comment: @ nhee  I'm glad you asked this question.  The files are of nearly identical size, roughly 100 kb.  Both save to the harddisk as .xls, but when the first report, the one which executes properly, is downloaded, it has an extension of .asp. http://tinypic.com/r/ofwxhl/8

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout Unfortunately, I cannot share the files with you.  They contain private information. :(

Comment: @ David GM In order to not seem non-compliant, I created the sub

`Sub test()
    Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
End Sub`

This sub performed similarly, with it executing immediately on one spreadsheet and taking several seconds on the other.  The issue is with how this particular statement is executed in relation to the spreadsheet.  Furthermore, I have multiple instances of each type of report and the sub performs similarly on each, so that it is not an issue of an individual file being corrupt.

Comment: I have multiple lines of code in a routine that set the the font to bold in different cells. The first execution takes about 10 seconds and the second one (and on) are instantaneous. When I clear the sheet and run the routine again, the first execution is instantaneous. When I close Excel and reopen, the first execution takes about 3 seconds and then is instant. I'm guessing if I shut my system down, it will return to 10 seconds. Maybe you could add a mock `font.bold` line when the workbook is opened to "wake up" whatever makes that first bold take so long.

Comment: Putting a bold = true statement in the Workbook_Open event code worked for me. See posted answer.

Comment: This was working, but it must have just been a coincidence because it's taking 3 seconds on the first attempt again. Answer rescinded.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of reasons. The main in my opinion being that the changes require `ScreenUpdating` and both Worksheets use a different amount of memory to compute your Worksheet layout e.g. having shapes, pivots, charts, hidden rows etc.

To workaround this turn off `ScreenUpdating` before your computations. Then turn it on again like below

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Your code here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Additionally to optimize your code utilize the following:

1. Turn off `AutomaticCalculations`
2. Save your file as binary Excel: `.xslb`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I have tried them, but unfortunately still see no improvement in performance.

Comment: Here is a thought: Since the spreadsheets seem similar and the statement targets a particular cell, might the problem lie with the individual cell?  Is there an easy way to list the attributes of a given cell?

Comment: I found that I can recreate the delay on the "good" sheet by saving it to the harddisk, as either .xls or .xlsm.  If I close the spreadsheet and then reopen it, the bold statement causes a delay.  Typically, the "good" sheet is being opened from a web download prompt (http://oi61.tinypic.com/ofwxhl.jpg).  It then seems that the problem is related to _where_ the file is stored, rather than _how_ it is stored.  But this reasoning is inherently flawed considering that when a file is opened from a web download, it is stored in 'temp.'